# ActiveAdmin add filter to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have some properties on an active admin model, which can have a LOT of different values, so right now I'm displaying them using checkboxes:

```
  PropertyType.find_each do |pt|
    f.input :property_values
    f.input :property_values, label: pt.display_name,  as: :check_boxes, collection: pt.property_values.order(name: :asc, display_name: :asc).load , multiple: true
  end
```

What I would like to do is to add an input field, in which while i'm writing, it filters the whole checkboxes list, only displaying the ones that matches the input field.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check out [chosen_rails gem](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails).

In active_admin it will look something like this:

```
f.input :property_values,
  label: pt.display_name,
  as: :check_boxes,
  collection: pt.property_values.order(name: :asc, display_name: :asc).load,
  input_html: { class: 'chosen-select' },
  multiple: true
```

The only thing I haven't tried it with check_boxes, but with `as: :select`, and it works perfectly. I think select would be doing the same for you, since you have `multiple: true`

Comment: didn't work. It just looks the same. I wish i could add an input field so you can type like "bl" and the checkboxes list would filtered and just appear "blue" "light blue" etc. (not displaying "red" "yellow" etc)

Comment: chosen rails gem working (at least for me) in exactly the way you describe - I start typing, and it shortens the list of select options to what matches my input

Comment: Worked now. The thing was that your post says "class: 'chosen-input'" and it should say 'chosen-select'. If you edit your question i will accept it :)