# ActiveAdmin Filter Time Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activeadmin

When I search a User by `email`, which defaults to "contains", and purposely put in something I know it won't find, it times out and I get the standard "Application Error" page, the status being 503. Logs:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/manage/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bemail_contains%5D=zamm&commit=Filter&order=id_desc" host=www.appname.com request_id=4041fb8b-c14d-45ca-bdba-280d78bac6f3 fwd="198.0.42.137" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

If I search by `last_name` with a name I know doesn't exist, it does what it's supposed to, renders a `No User's Found` message.

Any idea why it would time out searching by email but not other attributes?

Using standard ActiveAdmin filters, ie

```
filter :first_name
filter :last_name
filter :email
filter :role, as: :select, collection: User::ROLES
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914785/activeadmin-add-filter-to-form/26925717#26925717. It is not the answer to your question, but could serve a nice workaround (in short - it won't allow you to hit search with non-existing value)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks man. I'll check that gem out, seems pretty rad if it all works properly.